# dig does not receive an answer

Tags: bind, dig

bind config

```
zone "minskmag.by" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/named/minskmag.by";
};
```

zone file

```
$TTL    3600
@            IN      SOA     ns1.thestudio.by. root.thestudio.by. (2012041615 10800 3600 604800 86400)
             IN      NS      ns1.thestudio.by.
             IN      NS      ns2.thestudio.by.
             IN      A       178.159.244.101
```

command:

```
dig minskmag.by @ns1.thestudio.by
```

doesn't receive answer section

could anyone help me?

Comment: Is this ns1.thestudio.by config and named config was reloaded after adding this? Does server has any views configured?

Comment: yes, it is configs from ns1.thestudio.by
and bind server successfully reloaded
server has no views

Comment: Can you provide the `dig` output?  Is the query getting an `NXDOMAIN` or `SERVFAIL` response, or simply timing out?  What about if you `dig @localhost` from the server?

Comment: `dig minskmag.by @178.159.244.101`

`; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> minskmag.by @178.159.244.101`
`;; global options: +cmd`
`;; Got answer:`
`;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 31776`
`;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0`
`;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available`
`;; QUESTION SECTION:`
`;minskmag.by.   IN A`
`;; Query time: 472 msec`
`;; SERVER: 178.159.244.101#53(178.159.244.101)`
`;; WHEN: Mon Apr 16 21:15:54 2012`
`;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 29`

Comment: `named-checkzone minskmag.by /etc/bind/named/minskmag.by`


`zone minskmag.by/IN: loaded serial 2012041600`


`OK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your server simply does not know about zone you've configured.

1. Check permissions to zone file.
2. Check whether zone file lies where it should (you've used absolute file path - I'd avoid this as it complicates switching between chrooted and non-chrooted environment for named). Are you running named in chroot?
3. Check logs for any additional messages about your zone (enable logging in named or enable logging for daemon facility in syslog).

Answer (score -3):

Try this command:
route add default your.ip.address
service named restart
then try again the dig command.